# Web scraping using R without using Selenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to find some way to scrape the Tables in the page 'https://www.icicidirect.com/idirectcontent/Research/TechnicalAnalysis.aspx/balancesheet/tcs' using `R but not Selenium (RSelenium)`.

I have tried below -

```
library(rvest)
Link = 'https://www.icicidirect.com/idirectcontent/Research/TechnicalAnalysis.aspx/balancesheet/tcs'
read_html(Link) %>% html_nodes("#Table1") %>% html_text()
## character(0)
```

But with this code, I am getting blank value.

Really appreciate for the right pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is not in the html you are requesting from the site. It is loaded dynamically by the javascript on the page via an xhr POST request. You can discover this in Chrome or Firefox developer tools.

The good news is that you can still get what you want in R by following the same link that your browser does:

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://www.icicidirect.com/idirectcontent/"
url1 <- paste0(base_url, "Research/TechnicalAnalysis.aspx/balancesheet/tcs")
url2 <- paste0(base_url, "basemasterpage/ContentDataHandler.ashx?icicicode=TCS")

response_1 <- GET(url1) # This is the page you can't scrape

# Set the parameters for the POST call (found from developer tools)
parameters <- list(pgname = "BalanceSheet_NonBanking",
                   ismethodcall = 0,
                   mthname = "")

# Now post the form and we'll get our table as a response
response_2 <- POST(url2, body = parameters)

# Process it as you did before:
read_html(response_2) %>% html_nodes("#Table1") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks so much and Happy New Year.